# MouseOver sound effect, a Better way than this

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, mouseover

I need a sound on a mouse over event, I have this way but its problem comes from a delay between the mouse over and the sound playing, which is due (I supposed) the embed sound deal on the code. I would like to know if there is a better way using js/jquery). But not the new html5 audio tag which I don't want to implement in this particular case.

An ajax call loads the file, then I attached to the mouseOver a function named playSound()

```
function playSound()
{ 
  $setSound = document.getElementById("soundWrapper").innerHTML="<embed id='sound' src='href' type=audio/mpeg hidden=false autostart=true volume=12>";
}
```

Then to the mouseOut event a function named stopSound()

```
function stopSound()
{
  $stopSound = document.getElementById("soundWrapper").innerHTML="";
}
```

Nothing fancy but it does work. The problem as a said is the delay to playing the sound. Is there a way to play/stop the already embedded sound, not just embed a new one every time, or something alike?.

Thanks for your time and help.
Greetings.

Comment: Have you looked into using the `Audio` object? Or inserting the HTML5 audio element into the DOM?

Comment: Use an `<audio>` element and put it on the page, hidden. When you want to play its sound, call `.play()` on its Element reference. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/audio

Answer (score 1):

If you have your AJAX load an audio tag (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) into the desired place, you can play it using the .play() method in JS. Then it becomes really easy

```
$(YOURMOUSEOVERELEMENT).on('mouseover', function(){$('#sound').play()});
```

Then if you want to stop the audio when the mouse leaves:

```
$(YOURMOUSEOVERELEMENT).on('mouseout', function(){$('#sound').stop()});
```

Comment: Thanks both for your replies, but both of them use the audio tag (HTM5) and IE doesn't support it. Is there a way besides of the audio tag?. I need this to run in IE8 as good as in any other modern browser in this particular case. Thanks for any futher information.

Comment: You could change it to  `$(YOURMOUSEOVERELEMENT).on('mouseover', function(){$('#soundWrapper').html('<embed id='sound' src='href' type=audio/mpeg hidden=false autostart=true volume=12>')});`  and then to stop it would be   `$(YOURMOUSEOVERELEMENT).on('mouseover', function(){$('#soundWrapper').html('')});`

Comment: Sorry, that 2nd bit to stop the playing should be `$(YOURMOUSEOVERELEMENT).on('mouseout', function(){$('#soundWrapper').html('')});`